# Why most of methods in Collections class declared as static

Tags: collections

Can someone explain why most of methods in Collections class declared as static? I have looked for answers but haven't fount any.

Comment: What are you talking about? And why do you think they should require an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is utility class containing algorithms which are used to operate on Java collections. It's noninstantiable

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, this class has private constructor and you can not create its object.

Comment: It is the other way round: this class is not not meant to be instantiated. In other words: its idea is to only provide static methods; thus the ctor is private; as there is no sense in creating objects of this class. In that sense: your answer gets cause and effect backwards.

Comment: I agree with you on this.